# Rotation and pure rolling

Tags: rotational-dynamics

[image: Here f is friction and we are Appling a force F on right wards]

In this case how can the friction be more than the force applied

Can someone pls explain?

Comment: Can you add some more details? What exactly is going on in the drawing, and why do you think that the force of friction cannot be larger than the applied force?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well actually the question is slightly wrong.Friction is less than applied force but the torque due to friction is more than the applied torque.Here's why:

There can be two cases out of the situation :

Case 1: Applied torque(anticlockwise) is more than frictional torque(clockwise)($\tau _F > \tau_f$) so net torque is anticlockwise:

Then F.r>f.R and the tangential acceleration of contact point P is R.$\alpha$ towards right. So friction force must exceed applied force so that acceleration of centre of mass(or linear acceleration ) is along left and net acceleration of P is zero. So we have f>F.

Now we know that R>r .If f>F then f.R>F.r and $\tau _f > \tau_F$ i.e frictional torque exceeds applied torque. But in this case we had assumed that applied torque exceeds frictional torque. **So our assumption must have been wrong.**

Case 2:Frictional torque(clockwise) is more than Applied torque(anticlockwise)($\tau _f > \tau_F$) so net torque is clockwise:

Then f.R>F.r and the tangential acceleration of contact point P is R.$\alpha$ towards left. So applied force must exceed frictional force force so that acceleration of centre of mass(or linear acceleration ) is along right and net acceleration of P is zero. So we have F>f.

Now we know that R>r .Also F>f so it can be possible for f.R>F.r(this can be verified by taking hypothetical values of f,F,r,R.For example you can take f=2,F=3,R=10,r=2)  i.e our assumption is correct.

So we can conclude that for pure rolling in a spool the applied force exceeds frictional force but frictional torque exceeds applied torque.

[image][image]

Comment: Thanks a ton for the answer

Comment: Happy to Help !